# View returning in popup laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I am returning a view from controller, but instead of opening new page, the view is opening in popup which i assume is error message popup,. i am new in laravel.

Controller Code

```
public function postRegister () {

 return view('front.member.registerpayment')->with('amountUSD', $data['btc_withcom']);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using AJAX request.

In your controller…

```
public function postRegister () {

// do something to get your data
return response()->json(
[
    'data'=>$your_data
   ]
);
}
```

Then make a ajax request
First import jquery.
Then

```
$.ajax({
    url: ‘your url’,
    method: ‘POST’
    data: ‘pass any data to controller’
    success: function(data){
    // invoke popup with data
    // you can easily do this with jquery UI library
}
})
```

[Here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) is the complete example to open dialog box.

Hint: append your data to html before invoking